# how can I pass a service to a controller dynamically by some conditions

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using the ui-router module and have defined these states:

```
 .state('projects.create', {
            url: '/create',
            views: {
                'outer@': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/projects.create.html',
                    resolve: {
                        schoolyear: function(schoolyearService) {
                            return schoolyearService.createSchoolyear();
                        }
                     },
                    controller: 'ProjectWizardController'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('projects.edit', {
            url: '/edit',
            views: {
                'outer@': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/projects.edit.html',
                    resolve: {
                        schoolyear: function(schoolyearService) {
                            return schoolyearService.editSchoolyear();
                        }
                    },
                    controller: 'ProjectWizardController'
                }
            }
        })
```

As each of both ui-router states know which states they are they also know what dependencies should be passed to the ProjectWizardController.

When the projects.create state is activated I want to pass the CreateWizardDataService to the ProjectWizardController.
When the projects.edit state is activated I want to pass the EditWizardDataService to the ProjectWizardController.

HOW can I manually inject the service dependency into the ProjectsWizardController?

```
'use strict';
angular.module('schoolyearProjectModule').controller('ProjectWizardController',
    function ($scope, wizardDataService, $state, schoolyear) {
```

// wizardDataService => could be the CreateWizardDataService or EditWizardDataService

```
    // The wizardDataService is the individual service for an AddService or EditService
    // service contain the 3 same main properties: schoolyearData, schoolclasscodesData, timetableData

        wizardDataService.schoolyearData = schoolyear.schoolyearData;
        wizardDataService.schoolyearData = schoolyear.schoolclassCodesData;
        wizardDataService.schoolyearData = schoolyear.timetableData;

        // The if and else if should be injected into this Controller becaue the outside ui router states know their state edit/create
        if ($state.current.name === 'projects.create') {
            $scope.steps = [wizardDataService.schoolyearData, wizardDataService.schoolclassCodesData, wizardDataService.timetableData];
        }
        else if ($state.current.name === 'projects.edit') {
            $scope.steps = [wizardDataService.schoolyearData, wizardDataService.schoolclassCodesData, wizardDataService.timetableData];
        }

        $scope.steps = [wizardDataService.schoolyearData, wizardDataService.schoolclassCodesData, wizardDataService.timetableData];

        $scope.activeStep = $scope.steps[0];
        $scope.step = 0;
        var stepsLength = $scope.steps.length;

        $scope.isLastStep = function () {
            return $scope.step === (stepsLength - 1);
        };
        $scope.isFirstStep = function () {
            return $scope.step === 0;
        };
        $scope.getCurrentStep = function () {
            return $scope.activeStep.name;
        };
        $scope.getNextLabel = function () {
            return ($scope.isLastStep()) ? 'Submit' : 'Next';
        };
        $scope.previous = function () {
            if ($scope.step > 0) {
                $scope.step--;
                $scope.activeStep = $scope.steps[$scope.step];
            }
        };
        $scope.next = function () {

            if ($scope.isLastStep() && $scope.activeStep.isValid()) {
                $state.go('^');
            }
            else if ($scope.activeStep.isValid()) {
                $scope.step += 1;
                $scope.activeStep = $scope.steps[$scope.step];
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You could inject both, and choose the one you use based on the current state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways to do this:

Option 1 - Use resolve with a string as the value. As per the documentation:

> The resolve property is a map object. The map object contains
>   key/value pairs of:
>
> key – {string}: a name of a dependency to be injected into the
>   controller.
>
> factory - {string|function}: **If string, then it is an
>   alias for a service**. Otherwise if function, then it is injected and
>   the return value is treated as the dependency. If the result is a
>   promise, it is resolved before the controller is instantiated and its
>   value is injected into the controller.

Option 1 example:

```
.state('projects.create', {
        url: '/create',
        views: {
            'outer@': {
                templateUrl: 'views/projects.create.html',
                resolve: {
                    schoolyear: function(schoolyearService) {
                        return schoolyearService.createSchoolyear();
                    },
                    wizardDataService: 'CreateWizardDataService'
                 },
                controller: 'ProjectWizardController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('projects.edit', {
        url: '/edit',
        views: {
            'outer@': {
                templateUrl: 'views/projects.edit.html',
                resolve: {
                    schoolyear: function(schoolyearService) {
                        return schoolyearService.editSchoolyear();
                    },
                    wizardDataService: 'EditWizardDataService'
                },
                controller: 'ProjectWizardController'
            }
        }
    })
```

Option 2 - Use `$injector.get('CreateWizardDataService')` or `$injector.get('EditWizardDataService')` directly in your controller depending on which state you are in.

Comment: So there is no chance to get rid of the if and else if state checking inside the ProjectWizardController? I would like to get rid of those lines and make the ProjetWizardController more encapsulated/independend.

Comment: Based on the limited info supplied, I would make the CreateWizardDataService and EditWizardDataService dependent on schoolyearService, i.e. inject schoolyearService into the data service. And then expose a getSteps() method on the data service. That way the controller can just call wizardDataService.getSteps() without the if/else steps. This relies on using Option 1 in the answer, i.e. injecting the data service into the controller based on the state.

Comment: ah was I blind. Now I get options 1. The injected service is generic like I wanted, no if and else if needed as those 2 service of the same 3 properties each property for a page of the wizard!